# A Numpy Broadcasting Problem (need help to solve)

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I'm trying to accelerate a loop by using numpy broadcasting.  The loop uses the prior index position to create the current index position of an array.  My problem (I think) is that my broadcasting version appears to run the np.max() function before the broadcast?

LOOP VERIONS - WORKS FINE

```
#ARRAY SHAPES
#probObsInState.T.shape = (600,5)
#fAlpha_broadcast.shape = (600,5)
#fAlpha_loop.shape = (600,5)
#transitMatrix = (5,5)
n=600
for i in range(n):
    if i == 0:
        fAlpha_loop[i]=np.log2(probObsInState.T[:][i])+np.max(transitMatrix,axis=1)
    else:
        fAlpha_loop[i]=np.log2(probObsInState.T[:][i])+np.max(fAlpha_loop[i-1][:]+transitMatrix,axis=1)
```

BROADCAST VERSION - DOES NOT PRODUCE SAME ANSWER

```
#position zero I don't get from broadcast
fAlpha_broadcast[0] = np.log2(probObsInState.T[:][0])+np.max(transitMatrix,axis=1)

#need falpha_broadcast from [1:] to depend on prior value - but doesn't seem to work
fAlpha_broadcast[1:] = np.log2(probObsInState.T[:] [1:])+np.max(fAlpha_broadcast[:-1,np.newaxis]+transitMatrix,axis=1)
```

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to perform that operation like that. A single simple vectorised operation can't make use of values calculated as part of itself.

Comment: `[:]` doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: you connot use vectorization to speed up this computation as said before but you can use things like Numba or Cython to do it.

Comment: Thanks Ixop and Jerome.  I have been using cython from time to time, but have reached a limit for speed I seem to be able to achieve from cython (fully looped) compared to broadcasting.  Ah well.